# Dungeon Mastering: How to dungeon master a game about non-heroic peasants living in a village

Tags: combat, system-agnostic

How would I engage the PCs?

Say, I announced to them that a hurricane was going to blow over the village and destroy all the crops, kill a bunch of livestock, and ruin the whole thing.  What would the PCs, as non-heroic peasants, be able to do?  How would I give them a feeling of agency?

Say, a group of raiders attacks the village.  Would PCs have more than once choice on how to deal with the problem?  Ie. They shouldn't just feel like they're forced to go and ask the local noble to summon army and help them.  While that could be an adventure in itself (travel on the road with an element of survival and race against time), that probably isn't the only way to go about it.

---

How would the PCs be able to interact with life in the village?  Their could be intrigue, which they could get a leg up on by grinding out reputation with NPCs in order to get favours - but what sort of tasks would be fun and engaging?  I could make everything a minigame, but there may be a limit on how much fun can be had with milking cows, feeding chickens, cutting grass for hay, helping the harvest, etc.

Maybe those tasks would be assumed with a time management element (after all they're peasants who do peasant things; they don't need to declare that they're doing those things; it's a bit like making camp when resting in D&D), and combine it with the ability to spend it doing more than their share of the village's labour quotient.

Maybe some tasks might be hunting down a particularly nasty wolf who's been eating sheep.

I've got to break down the tasks into categories.

Bullshit Minigames like herding sheep, milking cows, feeding chickens, etc.
Management in the main game.
More important minigames for tasks like repairing a house.
A bit of 'dungeon delving' and combat for hunting down wolves in forests.
Intrigue within the village
Festival fisticuffs, wrestling minigames, archery, drinking games, etc.

---

What about for players who like puzzles?

Combat?  I'm thinking here, players could temporarily join a warband that's passing by to request a levy.  They could also hunt down a wolf, or do non-lethal combat unarmed (no fancy weapons or spells, which might be boring).

Dialogue is an easy one.

---

Any more suggestions from anyone?

Comment: This looks like a big, sprawling question. I think you could do with a bit more focus, try to figure out exactly what it is that is causing you problems. Is there a problem with playing it straight and leaving figuring out a solution to the players?

Comment: Yes, I want to play it straight, but I don't know how.  The OP is a brainstorm to see the different ways of playing it straight.  However, I also want the players to be in touch with the village and have a bit of a management aspect going on with their own house or plot of land, perhaps.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. While you are here please take the [tour]. Unfortunately this style of brainstorming and idea generation question is better suited to a forum rather than our Q&A style, but we can help you out :)  - follow the link: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/44723)

Comment: The expertise of this community are definitely a good match for this question - many people run "non-heroic" games of 5e, I know I have and I'm a fairly average DM! The question itself just needs to be workshopped a bit to get some focus as I'm not entirely sure what it's asking right now. Here's a link about how we can leverage expertise rather than just relying on facts: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: I think that there might be one objectively correct answer to this question as-is.